# Acessar valor de uma propriedade por meio de uma String

Tags: javascript, array

Suponha que tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
var pessoa = {
    nome: "João",
    animais: {
        cachorro: "Rex",
        gato: "Pipoca",
    }
}
```

preciso de uma função para fazer algo como isso:

```
var gatoDoJoao = pessoa["animais.gato"];
```

Sei que neste exemplo o correto é`pessoa.animais.gato`, mas quero que o valor seja acessado por meio de uma string.
Algo como: `var gatoDoJoao = acessar(pessoa, "animais.gato");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finalmente consegui resolver!

```
var obj = {
    nome: "João",
    animais: {
        gato: "Foo",
        cachorro: "Bar"
    }
};

function acessar(obj, prop){
    var tmp = obj;
    var campos = prop.split(".");

    for(var i in campos){
        if(tmp.hasOwnProperty(campos[i])){
            tmp = tmp[campos[i]];
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}

var nomeDoGato = acessar(obj, "animais.gato");
console.log(nomeDoGato);
```

Answer (score 4):

Vê-se que entende que os nomes das propriedades são apenas textos como chaves de um *array* associativo.

Elas são propriedades diferentes em níveis diferentes, portanto deve-se acessar como chaves diferentes.

```js
var pessoa = {
    nome: "João",
    animais: {
        cachorro: "Rex",
        gato: "Pipoca",
    }
}

console.log(pessoa["animais"]["gato"]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/PropertyByString.js).

Comment: Sei desse método também, porém procuro um meio de acessar com a string neste formato "animais.gato", pois esta string vem de um campo de texto.

como mencionado, uma função que receba o objeto e a string.
acessar(pessoa, "animais.gato");

Comment: Aí a questão é outra, você teria que analisar a *string*, separá-la e e usar da forma que apresentei. Sua pergunta não diz claramente que precisa ser assim, não diz quais os critérios, o que fazer quando vier texto inválido, etc. Portanto se a pergunta for por esse caminho ela não é clara e é ampla por pedir uma solução completa. Você até poderia fazer uma nova pergunta mais detalhada, mas teria que dar todos detalhes necessários e tentar fazer. Sem critério eu diria que basta fazer um `split(".")`, mas é uma forma bem ingênua de resolver isso.

Answer (score 1):

Possui uma forma um pouco mais fácil;

```
eval('pessoa.animais.gato');
```

> O argumento da função eval() é uma string. Se a string representa uma
>   expressão, eval() avalia a expressão. Se o argumento representa uma ou
>   mais declarações de JavaScript, eval() avalia as declarações. Não
>   chame o eval() para avaliar uma expressão aritmética; JavaScript
>   avalia expressões aritméticas automaticamente.

[MDN - EVAL](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)